# "Fake" DNS for a single host

Tags: dns, bind

I am running a bind9 dns server at my home network, serving for all my internal servers in my domain local  / 192.168.x.x - one of those, extweb.local 192.168.1.33 is also visible from the internet as home.sickel.net (well, not exactly, but you get the idea)

Is it possible to set up my internal dns so that it resolvs home.sickel.net as 192.168.1.33? All other hosts on sickel.net are run externally and should not be resolved by my internal dns.

(All this mainly to make things easier for the rest of the family, so that they always can refer to the server as home.sickel.net no matter if they are at home or accessing it through the www)

All the servers on my home network runs debian. They are all in the same subnet, connected through a single gateway to the internet.

Comment: You will need to describe the setup in more detail if you want valid responses.  What is the layout? E.g., DSL router, home.sickel.example and the other machines at home all hang of it? What OS is **home** running?  It would be easy enough to set-up bind in such a way that **home** handles all DNS queries, and passes anything OTHER than **homes** IPs off to your ISP DNS servers (slave set-up).

Comment: You need to override the lookups with a home.sickel.net zone in bind. The details are here: http://serverfault.com/a/223958

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure you can do it.  Take a look here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BIND9ServerHowto#Primary_Master_Server_configuration

```
red@ubuntu:/etc/bind$ cat named.conf.local
zone "home.sickel.net." {
             type master;
             file "/etc/bind/db.sickel.net";
        };

red@ubuntu:/etc/bind$ cat db.sickel.net
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     localhost. root.localhost. (
                              2         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      localhost.
home.sickel.net. IN     A       192.168.1.33
red@ubuntu:/etc/bind$ sudo service bind9 restart
 * Stopping domain name service... bind9 [ OK ]
 * Starting domain name service... bind9 [ OK ]
red@ubuntu:/etc/bind$ dig +short home.sickel.net @localhost
192.168.1.33
red@ubuntu:/etc/bind$ dig +short sickel.net @localhost
85.19.71.164
```

Now just change your /etc/resolv.conf to use 127.0.0.1 as the primary nameserver.

Comment: Your approach is flawed in that it will prevent a resolution for any host whose name is foobar.home.sickel.net.